# Can we turn a single telescope into Event Horizon Telescope?

Tags: telescopes

Event Horizon Telescope is a network of telescopes that sync together to focus on a distant object and act as one huge telescope.

I wonder if the same effect could be achieved with a single telescope?

Assuming we want to focus on a distant object D with whom we are familiar and can calculate its location at a given time. We also can calculate our location at a given time. 
So the idea is to start taking snapshots of D from a single telescope via different angles, each snapshot creates a new virtual telescope that gets frozen in place and time leaving only its snapshot behind, the next snapshot is happening after some short time, during which the Earth has moved. So it is coming from a new location now, hence we adjust the telescope angle to take it into account and focus on the same point.

Assuming that D is not changing between the snapshots, and omits exactly the same light as if we were taking all of the snapshots simultaneously, we can accomplish two things:

- Get some really nice pictures of remote objects
- Get a more accurate understanding of remote objects motions by correcting our knowledge about their locations by sharping our focus.

Has anyone already been trying to do it? What tools do I need to run this experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $D$ is changing with time. Remember, the aim of interferometry is to measure the phase differences in a wavefront across the telescope.

It is not possible to assess the relative position of the source and telescope (the source is moving as well!) to a fraction of the wavelength of light.

The event horizon telescope gets around this using "phase closure" techniques that use *simultaneous* measurements from at least three different locations.

Secondly, sources do vary. Unless you were observing a coherent source like a laser then there is no way you could extrapolate to estimate what the phase of the wave was backwards and forwards in time.

Thirdly, your proposal is exactly how astronomical observations are currently done!  A single telescope tracks an object and records a time series of data from that object. If it could be done with one telescope, don't you think we'd have heard by now?